# Ng-repeat inside ng-repeat angularJS

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, json

i'm working on a project in angularJS using AJAX and it's a post / comment system with like buttons. Everything is working so far except reading comments from Database which is supposed to be done using a 2nd ng-repeat inside the first one that is reading the posts.

I can recieve the json with data fine going to the page servicoLeituraComments.php, all data is there. I think the problem is with ng-repeat but I'm not sure how am i suppose to do it when it's inside another, i already tried "comments" or "p.comments" on it and none work. Also anything i type inside the 2nd ng-repeat won't appear on page neither. Here is the code.

> 

```
  <script>
    var app = angular.module('postsApp', []);
    var interval;

    app.controller('postsCtrl', function($scope) {
        $scope.toggle = false;
        $scope.texto = [];
        $scope.comment = [];
        $scope.comment = "";
        $scope.comments = "";
        $scope.posts = "";
        $scope.texto = "";
        $scope.idPost = 0;
        $scope.showBox = function(p){

          p.toggle = !p.toggle;


          if(interval == 0){
            interval = setInterval("angular.element($('#postsApp')).scope().servicoLeituraPosts()",1000);
          }else{
            clearInterval(interval);
            interval = 0;

          }
           servicoLeituraComments(p);
        };
        $scope.iniciaTimer = function(){
               interval = setInterval("angular.element($('#postsApp')).scope().servicoLeituraPosts()",1000);
        };
        $scope.servicoLeituraPosts = function(){        
                $.getJSON(
                        "servicoLeituraPosts.php",
                        {

                        },
                        function(jsonData)
                        {
                            $scope.posts = jsonData;
                            $scope.$apply();
                        });
        };
        $scope.servicoLeituraComments = function(p){        
                $.getJSON(
                        "servicoLeituraComments.php",
                        {
                            "idPost": p.idPost
                        },
                        function(jsonData)
                        {
                            $scope.comments = jsonData;
                            $scope.$apply();
                        });
        };
        $scope.addPost =  function(){                              
                $.post(
                    "addPostRest.php",
                    {
                        "texto" :  $scope.texto
                    },
                    function(dados)
                    {
                        $scope.texto = dados.indexOf("OK") >= 0 ? "" : "FALHOU";
                        $scope.$apply();
                   }
                );
        };
        $scope.addLike =  function(idPost){
                $.post(
                    "addLike.php",
                    {
                        "idPost" : $scope.idPost = idPost
                    },
                    function(dados)
                    {
                        $scope.texto = dados.indexOf("OK") >= 0 ? "" : "FALHOU";
                        $scope.$apply();
                    }
                );
            };
             $scope.addComment =  function(p){                              
                $.post(
                    "addComentarioRest.php",
                    {

                        "comment" : p.comment,
                        "idPost" : p.idPost
                    },
                    function(dados)
                    {
                        $scope.texto = dados.indexOf("OK") >= 0 ? "" : "FALHOU";
                        $scope.$apply();
                    }
                );
            };      

    });
</script>


<div class="panel panel-default">
        <div class="panel-heading">
            POSTS 
            <a class="btn btn-success pull-right" href="posts.php"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-refresh"/></a>          
        </div>

        <div class="panel-body">

            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="texto">Texto::</label>

                <textarea ng-model="texto" placeholder="Coloque aqui a mensagem..." class="form-control" rows="5" name="texto"></textarea>
            </div>

            <button ng-click="addPost()" class="btn btn-success btn-xs" type="button">Enviar</button>      

        </div>
</div>

<div class="posts" id="posts">
    <div class='row ng-scope' ng-repeat="p in posts" >
        <div class='col-md-12'>


            {{ p.nome }} -  {{ p.data }} <p><p>  
            {{ p.texto }}                <p><p>
            {{ p.numeroLikes }}  

            <button ng-click="addLike(p.idPost)" class="btn btn-default btn-xs" type="button">Like</button>    

            <span class="abrir_comentario" ng-click="showBox(p)">Comentários</span>

            <div ng-show="p.toggle" id="comentarios">
                <div class="comentarios">



                    <div class="form-group">
                        <textarea ng-model="p.comment" placeholder="Coloque aqui a mensagem..." class="form-control" rows="3" name="texto"></textarea>
                    </div>


                    <p><p><p><button ng-click="addComment(p)" class="btn btn-success btn-xs" type="button">Enviar</button>

                    <div class="comments" id="comments">
                        <div class='row ng-scope' ng-repeat="c in p.comments" >   
                            <div class='col-md-12'>

                                  {{ c.nome }} -  {{ c.data }} <p><p>  
                                  {{ c.texto }}                <p><p>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>


                </div>
            </div> <p>


        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Here is JSon array from servicoLeituraPosts.php

```
[
{
    "idPost":"12",
            "data":"2017-06-21 01:17:05",
            "nome":"joao",
            "texto":"Ola",
            "idAutor":"3",
            "numeroLikes":"3"
    },
    {
    "idPost":"13",
            "data":"2017-06-21 01:24:10",
    "nome":"joao",
            "texto":"Eu sou o joao",
            "idAutor":"3",
            "numeroLikes":"3"
}
```

]

And here is JSon array from servicoLeituraComments.php

```
[
{
    "nome":"joao",
    "texto":"12345",
    "data":null},
    {
    "nome":"joao",
    "texto":"1234",
    "data":null
}
```

]

Comment: Can you give an example of what the `$scope.posts` array looks like?

Comment: I edited question and added both JSons arrays

Answer (score 0):

So there are two things I am seeing here.  The first is that the JSON you are trying to get comments from doesn't have a comments property.  If it did it would be like this:

```
{
        "idPost":"12",
        "data":"2017-06-21 01:17:05",
        "nome":"joao",
        "texto":"Ola",
        "idAutor":"3",
        "numeroLikes":"3"
        "comments": []  //This is missing, these would be p.comments
}
```

The second thing I see is that you have a `<textarea>` with an `ng-model="p.comments"`.  Are you trying to use this to add comments to `$scope.posts`?  If so you should change that model to something like `ng-model="newComment"` and `addComment()` should find `$scope.newComment` and push it to `$scope.posts`

**Try this:**

```
ng-click="addComment($index)"

$scope.addComment = function(index){
  $scope.posts[index].comments.push($scope.newComment);
  $scope.newComment = '';
}
```

**Edit**

It doesn't matter if you get the posts in one JSON, and the comments in another.  The only problem I can see is the way your comments JSON is.  There would need to be another field for the comments to know which posts to attach themselves to.  Like this:

```
{
    "nome":"joao",
    "texto":"12345",
    "data":null,
    "idPost": "12"  //This is how you would know that this comment goes to this post
}
```

Comment: My question in this case is if i have to get comments on the same mysql query where i'm getting posts? Or is it possible to save the comments json into the posts one? because i'm supposed to load comments separated from posts and not sure it works this way

Comment: I did this, json now shows idPost, but i don't see how will comments attach to posts, do i have to change addComment function still?

Comment: When you load the data you could do a nested forEach. See here: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/QgRZEp  Now, each post should have a comments array and each post will be sorted.  p.comments in your ng-repeat should now work too.  This isn't the most efficient way of doing this, but it shouldn't matter unless your JSONs are insanely huge.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you all, i managed to solve this problem, i'm treating both ng-repeats individually one being inside the other, since I have 2 JSONs with data that relate with each other by ID.